# Wordpress filter WP_List_Table on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, filtering, custom-post-type

**I have a custom post type (College Course) that I have set up a custom WP_List_Table for, as an extended class.**

I have the list working fine, and can sort my chosen columns, and have my actions set up and working.

> But I'm getting stuck on filtering.  I have 2 drop down boxes as
>   filter options (Course Title and Status [of application]).  The
>   propblem is when i hit the filter button I'm getting...
>
> 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'

I'm pretty sure the reason is because it is a custom post type and I need to include the parameters `post_type=course` into the url, which is what I had to do with the action links, but I can't figure out how to get that into the url when filtering.

I'm using the `extra_tablenav()` function to do the filtering and have my query ready to catch the additional parameters of filter-course and filter-status in the `prepare_item` function but it never gets there.

Comment: you must have to wrap your `display()` inside a `form` tag.

Comment: yes it is already inside a form tag.

Comment: try by setting post method.